# Protocol specific channel handlers

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing an application server that will receive **SIP** and **DNS** messages from the network.

When I receive a message from the network, I understand from the documentation that at first, I get a `ChannelBuffer`. I would like to determine which kind of message has been received (SIP or DNS) and to decode it.

To determine the message type, I can dedicate port to each type of message, but I would be interested to know if there exist another solution for that. My question is more about how to decode the `ChannelBuffer`.

Is there a `ChannelHandler` provided by Netty to decode SIP or DNS messages? If not, what would be the right place in the type hierarchy to write my custom `ChannelHandler`?

To illustrate my question, let's take as example the `HttpRequestDecoder`, the hierarchy is:

```
java.lang.Object
    org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler
        org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder
            org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder<HttpMessageDecoder.State>
                org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder
                    org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder
```

Also, do I need to use two different `ChannelHandler` for decoding and encoding, or is there a possibility to use a single `ChannelHandler` for both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a requirement for port unification (an example [here](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/)), i.e. receiving different protocols on the same port, then you would have to detect the protocol in a handler and take appropriate actions. Could be as simple as inserting different handlers in the pipe line.

However, I find it very improbable that SIP and DNS would share the same port, hence no need to complicate matters.

I haven't seen a SIP decoder/encoder for Netty, but depending on what you want to do with the message, the HTTP decoder is a a very good starting point (and could be made simpler since chunking is not supported in SIP).

I would strongly recommend not to try to combine DNS and SIP decoding in one handler (or any other combination for that matter). Keep the handlers as simple and coherent as possible. Combine handlers instead, if needed.

Comment: The HttpRequestDecoder inherits indirectly from FrameDecoder. Since I use UDP, is it relevant for my SIP decoder to also inherit from FrameDecoder? Also, in my last question, I didn't mean combining DNS and SIP decoding in one handler but encoding and decoding in one handler (possibly using a handler for upstream and downstream).

Comment: As for UDP and FrameDecoder: I don't think it hurts, but you must make sure that #messageReceived() gets the complete datagram packet in one call, since the Content-Length header is not mandatory for UDP.